# How to group documents by field in elastic search using spring

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have user document which has various fields including addressId. I want list of user with different addressId. If two user have same addressId then return any one user and skip other one.

I am trying to group user by addressId but its not working.

```
SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(boolQueryBuilder).
            addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("addressId").field("addressId").size(1)).
            withPageable(new PageRequest(page, size)).build();
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to add a [top hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) `subaggregation` with a size of 1. That will return one document (i.e. user in your case) per addressId field.

```
SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
    .withQuery(boolQueryBuilder)
    .addAggregation(AggregationBuilders
    .terms("addressId")
    .field("addressId")
    .size(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
    .subaggregation(AggregationBuilders.topHits("justOneUserPerAddressId)
         .setSize(1)
    )
    .withPageable(new PageRequest(page, size)).build();
```

Comment: Still it is not working. What is "justOneUserPerAddressId"??

Comment: Aggregations have to have a "name" which can be any string. This name is used to retrieve the results of the aggregation in the search response. `justOneUserPerAddressId` is the agg name.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not working"? Is it a exception? What is the json of the response? What, specifically, isn't working?

Comment: I am getting all user with same addressId, that means aggregation is not working

Comment: Are you looking at the aggregation part of the response? It appears at the bottom part of the response after all the Search Hits.

Comment: @NehaPateliya Can you post the response that you are seeing? And a sample document that shows the user and addressId fields?

Comment: Documents :[{"id":"1", "name":"riya", "addressId":"12345"},{"id":"2", "name":"rioo", "addressId":"12345"},{"id":"3", "name":"ram", "addressId":"45678"},{"id":"1", "name":"rakesh", "addressId":"45678"}]

Comment: Documents :[{"id":"1", "name":"riya", "addressId":"12345"},{"id":"2", "name":"rioo", "addressId":"12345"},{"id":"3", "name":"ram", "addressId":"45678"},{"id":"1", "name":"rakesh", "addressId":"45678"}]                                                                                    Response : Same as documents                                                          But i want in response : [{"id":"1", "name":"riya", "addressId":"12345"},{"id":"3", "name":"ram", "addressId":"45678"}]

Comment: You need to extract the aggregation results from the response. It looks like you are only looking at the search hits which will likely contain all the documents. See here for the structure of a terms agg response: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html